# Create a SwiftUI line graph using arrays and the Swift Charts framework

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts

In a SwiftUI app, I'm trying to pass an array of Y values to the Swift Charts framework to draw a line graph. I would like to create the X values based on the length or count of the Y data. I tried the approach shown below but it doesn't work because Charts wants the data as an array of structs. Is there a way to pass arrays directly to the Charts framework?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let ydata = [1, 4.5, 3, 6, 7, 5.2, 9, 12.5]
    let xdata = Array(0..<ydata.count)
    let data = [xdata, ydata]

    var body: some View {
        Chart(data) {
            LineMark(
                x: .value("X values", $0),
                y: .value("Y values", $1)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let ydata = [1, 4.5, 3, 6, 7, 5.2, 9, 12.5]

    var body: some View {
        Chart(0..<ydata.count, id: \.self)
        { nr in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("X values", nr),
                y: .value("Y values", ydata[nr])
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `nr` represent?

Comment: It is counting array elements.

Comment: This is a cleaner approach than the other answer. Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array of tuples, here I am using a computed property for the data

```
var data: [(Int, Double)] {
    Array(zip(Array(0..<ydata.count), ydata))
}
```

When using a tuple we need to tell `Chart` what the id is so the use of `data` is a little different

```
var body: some View {
    Chart(data, id: \.0) { tuple in
        LineMark(
            x: .value("X values", tuple.0),
            y: .value("Y values", tuple.1)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you for the help. You could also use `$0` and `$1` for the x and y values.